# Как сделать n копий бинаря программы на c++?

Tags: c++

Как сделать n копий бинаря программы на c++?

Comment: Сделайте одну копию, повторите ещё `n - 1` раз.

Comment: @VladD логично, но как сделать 1?

Comment: скопировать и вставить видимо

Comment: @pavel самостоятельно чтобы копировалась

Comment: копирование самой себе не отличается от копирования другого файла ничем.

Comment: @true: Любым из путей, да хоть через [`std::system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system).

Comment: @VladD можете код показать?

Comment: @true: Код чего? `std::system((std::string("copy \"") + srcpath + "\" \"" + dstpath + "\"").c_str())`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

В `C++17` можно так:

```
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    const int copies = 42;
    for (int i = 0; i < copies; ++i)
        std::filesystem::copy("binary", "binary." + std::to_string(i));
}
```

В `VS2015` будет выглядеть так:

```
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    const int copies = 42;
    for (int i = 0; i < copies; ++i)
        std::tr2::sys::copy("binary", "binary." + std::to_string(i));
}
```

А в `GCC6.1` так:

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>

int main()
{
    const int copies = 42;
    for (int i = 0; i < copies; ++i)
        std::experimental::filesystem::copy("binary", "binary." + std::to_string(i));
}
```